# Replication with only update and insert

Tags: mysql, linux

I have set up my replication but I want to delete some outdated data from my master tables. Is it possible that say if I have 10 records at master and I delete 5 of them but I want those 10 records to remain on the slave?

Comment: I would suggest don't use native replication. Keep the slave up to date with triggers or with custom polling code that runs on a schedule.

Answer (score 3):

If you're just going to delete this extra data manually on the odd occasion, you can simply turn off the binary logging for the current session. On the MySQL prompt run the following:

`set sql_log_bin=0;`

Then any query you enter won't be sent to the binary log, and thus won't be sent across to the slaves.

Once you're finished, re-activate binary logging with

`set sql_log_bin=1;`

Reference: [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-sql-log-bin.html)

Answer (score -1):

<sub>Solution for **PostgreSQL**:</sub>

<sub>We can avoid using rules</sub>

<sub>- Stop slave daemons</sub>
 <sub>- Create `ON DELETE` and `ON UPDATE DO INSTEAD NOTHING`</sub>

<sub>`CREATE RULE void_delete AS ON DELETE TO reptest DO INSTEAD NOTHING`</sub>

<sub>- rule Apply RULE on table</sub>

<sub>`ALTER TABLE reptest ENABLE REPLICA RULE void_delete;`</sub>

<sub>Now, you can notice below that `DELETE` has no impact on Slave Node</sub>

---

**EDIT**

For **MySQL** we can create `Trigger` like:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER PreventDeletion
BEFORE DELETE ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  IF old.id IN (1,2) THEN -- Will only abort deletion for specified IDs
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' -- "unhandled user-defined exception"
      -- Here comes your custom error message that will be returned by MySQL
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'This record is sacred! You are not allowed to remove it!!';
  END IF;

END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ  i edited my answer, Previous one for  postgresql so i added for mysql, Here we can avoid deletion using trigger

Comment: OK. Will this trigger allow the rows to be deleted on master but kept on slave?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ i think we have to add "slave-skip-errors = 45000" in slave my.cnf file. Then replication will be continued and records are exist on slave.

But its not tested, will get-back to you asap after testing.

Comment: It's working fine